Access Android application variants / library variants in buildSrc
I am migrating my gradle files to kotlin dsl.  My current setup in Groovy is I have a sonar.gradle, a projectjacoco.gradle and a modulegradle.gradle all included in my build.gradle.  I have now migrated my build.gradle to build.gradle.kts.  I understand I now need to re-write these external gradle files in kotlin-dsl and include them in the buildSrc folder structure:
e.g.
buildSrc
|__src
      |__main
            |__kotlin
                     |__modulegradle.build.kts


And then add them as a plugin.
My question is, how do I access the android baseappmodule extension inside those gradle files? e.g.
    android.applicationVariants.forEach { variant ->
        val variantName = variant.name.replaceFirstChar { if (it.isLowerCase()) it.titlecase(Locale.ENGLISH) else it.toString() }
        val testTaskName = "test${variantName}UnitTest"

but within the gradle.kts file within the buildSrc folder structure
I followed this vid on creating gradle plugins, however it didn't give me the functionality I needed.  So if anyone can help me, I wish to be able to access the android application / library variants from gradle files within the buildSrc folder structure e.g. in modulegradle.build.kts
Any and all help, tips, advice is greatly appreciated.

You need to import the artifact containing the Android application or library plugin in the buildSrc build.gradle.kts file to use it in a script plugin in buildSrc:
// buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:8.3.2")
}

Or for the library plugin:
// buildSrc/build.gradle.kts

dependencies {
    implementation("com.android.library:com.android.library.gradle.plugin:8.3.2")
}

Then you can apply the plugin in the script plugin:
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
}

